# Extract numerical value from a form <input type = "text">

Tags: android, input

Can someone tell me how I can extract numerical value from a form using multiple .
I am creating an app with a simple calculating function , however,  brings up the default qwerty keyboard that has a minus available.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the inputType to number or numberDecimal
example

```
android:inputType="number"
```

or

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: Thanks Nolly J , I'll give it a try